# Switch in different hash values to a combination array, and perform a calculation that ranks the first array - Ruby on rails

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, combinations

I have a few arrays that contain the same value, but have different keys associated to them. In this case, I have names of *Teams* and *Drivers* that have an associated *Price* and *Points* value. I have used 4 for each but there could be any number in either, both being decimals.

```
# DRIVER AND TEAM ARRAYS
driver_points = { "john" => 20.1, "mike" => 19.3, "paul" => 15.6, "mark" => 1.1 }
driver_price = { "john" => 4.0, "mike" => 5.0, "paul" => 6.0, "mark" => 2.1 }
team_points = { "cowboys" => 20.1, "bears" => 19.3, "lions" => 15.6, "united" => 2.8 }
team_price = { "cowboys" => 1.0, "bears" => 2.0, "lions" => 3.0, "united" => 2.4 }
```

I have turned the *driver_price* and *team_price* hashes into an array that gives me all the combinations less than or equal to a target value. With the condition that it can only contain 1 team and 3 drivers. I now want to rank those price combinations, by highest points. So I'm hoping there is a way that, in my current combinations I can substitute in the equivalent *points* value for each key, sum the points, and then rank the combinations by the points. I'd also like that rather than my combinations containing numbers that the Keys are used instead.

Here is my current code (giving me all the combinations by the target). And also a line at the bottom which is totalling each combination.

```
 # ALL COMBINATIONS OF DRIVERS AND TEAMS BASED ON BUDGET AND ARRAY
team = team_price.values.permutation(1).to_a
driver = driver_price.values.permutation(3).to_a
target = 13.5
array = team.product(driver)
res = array.select {|i| i.map(&:sum).sum <= target}.compact
t1 = res.map {|i| i[0]}
d2 = res.map {|i| i[1].flatten.sort}
combo = t1.zip(d2).uniq
full_combo = combo.flatten.each_slice(4).to_a

# TOTAL COST OF COMBINATION
total_cost = combo.map {|budget| budget.map(&:sum).sum}

# OUTPUT
@test1 = full_combo, total_cost
```

Which is outputting (All price combinations and totalling combo):

`[[[1.0, 2.1, 4.0, 5.0], [1.0, 2.1, 4.0, 6.0], [2.0, 2.1, 4.0, 5.0], [2.4, 2.1, 4.0, 5.0]], [12.1, 13.1, 13.1, 13.5]]`

I would like to rank these combinations, but by the equivalent *points* value. So hoping I can switch in the points, sum it up, and then rank the combos highest to lowest based on this and also display the Keys rather than values. So something like this:

1. Convert current combo to key equivalent:

`[[cowboys, mark, john, mike], [cowboys, mark, john, paul], [bears, mark, john, mike], [united, mark, john, mike]]`

2. Use this to switch in the *points* hash values and sum each combo:

`[[60.6], [56.9], [59.8], [43.4]]`

3. Then use the Points Sums to rank each combo. Ideal output:

| Combo | Total Price | Total Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cowboys, mark, john, mike | 12.1 | 60.6 |
| bears, mark, john, mike | 13.1 | 59.8 |
| cowboys, mark, john, paul | 13.1 | 56.9 |
| united, mark, john, mike | 13.5 | 43.4 |

Comment: You don't need to put Ruby on Rails in the title of the question, the tag system will make it searchable.

Comment: I'm finding your question hard to follow but the first thing I would look at would be restructuring the data. Something like `drivers = { "john" => { points: 20.1, price: 4 } ... }` would be easier to understand.

Comment: How does this differ in any significant way from your previous post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75247843/sort-by-sum-the-outcome-of-a-combination-based-on-another-value-in-a-hash

Comment: Progressed from then, and specifically asking to switch in the data. Spending so much time doing anything but trying to help is a common theme

Comment: @user3574603 thanks I will take a look at nested hashes to see if that can help

Comment: Further to @anothermh's observation, this is really a pure-Ruby question, so you could remove the tag "ruby-on-rails" as well.

Comment: Also, "arrays", "hash" and "combinations" are so commonplace in Ruby that I doubt it would be helpful to anyone doing searches for you to have included them as tags. I think you just need one tag, "Ruby".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are given the hashes `team_price`, `driver_price`, `team_points` and `driver_points` and the maximum price of a *combination*, which consists of one team and three drivers:

```
target = 13.5
```

---

We first need variables holding the teams and the drivers.

```
teams = team_price.keys
  #=> ["cowboys", "bears", "lions", "united"]
```

```
drivers = driver_price.keys
  #=> ["john", "mike", "paul", "mark"]
```

---

Looking ahead, we will be needing to sum both prices and points for given combinations. It therefore makes sense to create a method that does that.

```
def add_up(combo, ht, hd)
  t, d = combo
  ht[t] + hd.values_at(*d).sum
end
```

If, for example,

```
combo = ["cowboys", ["john", "mike", "paul"]]
```

then the total of prices for that combo is

```
add_up(combo, team_price, driver_price)
  #=> 16.0
```

See [Hash#values_at](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) and [Array#sum](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-sum).

---

We need to compute an array of all combinations for which the sum of prices does not exceed `target`. First compute all combinations of three drivers.

```
all_driver_combos = drivers.combination(3).to_a
  #=> [["john", "mike", "paul"], ["john", "mike", "mark"],
  #    ["john", "paul", "mark"], ["mike", "paul", "mark"]]
```

See [Array#combination](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-combination).

Next construct all combinations.

```
all_combos = teams.product(all_driver_combos)
  #=> [["cowboys", ["john", "mike", "paul"]],
  #    ["cowboys", ["john", "mike", "mark"]],
  #    ["cowboys", ["john", "paul", "mark"]],
  #    ["cowboys", ["mike", "paul", "mark"]],
  #    ["bears", ["john", "mike", "paul"]],
  #    ["bears", ["john", "mike", "mark"]],
  #    ["bears", ["john", "paul", "mark"]],
  #    ["bears", ["mike", "paul", "mark"]],
  #    ["lions", ["john", "mike", "paul"]],
  #    ["lions", ["john", "mike", "mark"]],
  #    ["lions", ["john", "paul", "mark"]],
  #    ["lions", ["mike", "paul", "mark"]],
  #    ["united", ["john", "mike", "paul"]],
  #    ["united", ["john", "mike", "mark"]],
  #    ["united", ["john", "paul", "mark"]],
  #    ["united", ["mike", "paul", "mark"]]]
```

See [Array#product](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-product).

Next extract from `all_combos` those for which the sum of prices does not exceed `target`.

```
valid_combos = all_combos.select do |c|
  add_up(c, team_price, driver_price) <= target
end
  #=> [["cowboys", ["john", "mike", "mark"]],
  #    ["cowboys", ["john", "paul", "mark"]],
  #    ["bears", ["john", "mike", "mark"]],
  #    ["united", ["john", "mike", "mark"]]]
```

If desired we could substitute out `all_driver_combos` and chain `all_combos`:

```
valid_combos = teams.product(drivers.combination(3).to_a)
                    .select do |c|
                       add_up(c, team_price, driver_price)<=target
                     end
```

---

Lastly, we wish to sort the `valid_combos` by the sum of points for each element of `valid_combos`.

```
ordered = valid_combos.sort_by do |c|
  -add_up(c, team_points, driver_points)
end
  #=> [["cowboys", ["john", "mike", "mark"]],
  #    ["bears", ["john", "mike", "mark"]],
  #    ["cowboys", ["john", "paul", "mark"]],
  #    ["united", ["john", "mike", "mark"]]]
```

​See [Enumerable#sort_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by).

Notice that I have negated the value returned by `add_up` so that the sort is from largest to smallest. One could alternatively write

```
ordered = valid_combos.sort_by do |c|
  add_up(c, team_points, driver_points)
end.reverse
```

---

We could examine the totals of prices and points for each element of `ordered` as follows.

```
ordered.map do |c|
  { c=>{ price: add_up(c, team_price, driver_price),
         points: add_up(c, team_points, driver_points) } }  
end
  #=> [{["cowboys", ["john", "mike", "mark"]]=>
  #        {:price=>12.1, :points=>60.6}},
  #    {["bears", ["john", "mike", "mark"]]=>
  #        {:price=>13.1, :points=>59.8}},
  #    {["cowboys", ["john", "paul", "mark"]]=>
  #        {:price=>13.1, :points=>56.9}},
  #    {["united", ["john", "mike", "mark"]]=>
  #        {:price=>13.5, :points=>43.3}}]
```

Comment: Hi @Cary, thank you so so much for this! Your walkthroughs are amazing and are so useful in understanding how you go about things. My only question is, in the final ordered.map output, the third combination is showing as: {["cowboys", ["john", "paul", "mark"]]=>{:price=>13.1, :points=>56.900000000000006}}. All the other combinations are working perfectly as shown above, just this one seems to be having a problem with the points decimal? Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you found it helpful. The mile-long float is just round-off error. It's interesting you noticed that as I just rounded it in my answer. You obviously ran the code. If needed, you can avoid the round-off error (in financial applications, for example) by using the [BigDecimal](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) class.